# How to identify position of a button with respect to a grid which contains a set of buttons

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am a beginner at using WPF.

I have wrote some xaml code in order to make a tic tac toe game.

I have a grid with 3 x 3 cells. I have put a button inside each cell of the grid.

I want to print out the position of the button with respect to the grid(i.e. row number and column number) when I press the button.

This is the xaml code :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Test Window" Height="500" Width="500" BorderBrush="#FA0D0D0D">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Name ="b1" Grid.Column=" 0" Grid.Row=" 0" Click="button_Click" />
    <Button Name ="b2" Grid.Column=" 0" Grid.Row=" 1" Click="button_Click" />
    <Button Name ="b3" Grid.Column=" 0" Grid.Row=" 2" Click="button_Click" />
    <Button Name ="b4" Grid.Column=" 1" Grid.Row=" 0" Click="button_Click" />
    <Button Name ="b5" Grid.Column=" 1" Grid.Row=" 1" Click="button_Click" />
    <Button Name ="b6" Grid.Column=" 1" Grid.Row=" 2" Click="button_Click" />
    <Button Name ="b7" Grid.Column=" 2" Grid.Row=" 0" Click="button_Click" />
    <Button Name ="b8" Grid.Column=" 2" Grid.Row=" 1" Click="button_Click" />
    <Button Name ="b9" Grid.Column=" 2" Grid.Row=" 2" Click="button_Click" />

</Grid>
</Window>
```

This is the C# code :

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    static int symbol;
    static int[][] game;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        symbol = 1;
        game = new int[3][];
        game[0] = new int[3];
        game[1] = new int[3];
        game[2] = new int[3];

    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        if (symbol == 1)
        {
            b.Content = "x";
            symbol = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            b.Content = "o";
            symbol = 1;
        }
    }



}

}
```

Inside the `button_Click` method I want to print the row number and column number of the grid, where that button is placed. How can I obtain that information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may get the row and column index by these static methods of Grid:

```
int row = Grid.GetRow(b);
int column = Grid.GetColum(b);
```

The methods return the values of the [attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column`.